# Start different Storyboard depending on user login-status at boot (Xamarin.iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm converting my Android App to iOS. I already created the login screen and a user can log in. If he enters the correct credentials his data is stored using `NSUSerDefault`.

What I don't know is how to achieve that when the app starts it checks the NSUserDefault for the values and decides  wether the user has to login or not.

Since Segues can't be made programmatically like in Android (`StartActivity()`) and need a button or something similar what would be the solution to my problem?

Comment: You probably don't need 2 different storyboards. I usually always start with the login view controller and let that check for credentials. If it's successful, then it pushes your next view controller and removes itself from the stack. This really depends on your hierarchy though, are you using a `UINavigationController`? Otherwise, you can change the `Window.RootViewController` on your app delegate to replace the view controller. As a side note, `NSUserDefault` is not a good place for credentials. Credentials belong in Key Chain.

Answer (score 0):

on `AppDelegate` class:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {

            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method


            UIViewController yourViewController = UIStoryboard.FromName("yourStoryboard",NSBundle.MainBundle).InstantiateViewController("yourViewController_StoryboardID");


            this.Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            UINavigationController navigationController = new UINavigationController(yourViewController);

            this.Window.RootViewController = navigationController;
            this.Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();


            return true;
        }
```